# JWT Token expiration time increase

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have integrated JWT token with django-restframwork, here I have setted expiration time 15mints `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA` but it is getting expire before mentioned time(1mints) and I need to refresh the token for proceeding... 
PFB me configuration

```
Python 3.5
Django==2.0.5
djangorestframework==3.8.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==3.2.3
```

Setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
} 

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=900),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
}
```

Please help, am I doing any mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `djangorestframework-simplejwt` but your config is for `djangorestframework-jwt`. Please uninstall `djangorestframework-simplejwt` and install `djangorestframework-jwt` instead.

`pip uninstall djangorestframework-simplejwt`

then

`pip install djangorestframework-jwt`
More details [here](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)

Comment: wouldn't the best library to implement jwt in django be `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` (https://github.com/jazzband/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) instead of `djangorestframework-jwt` (https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt) since the latter is now unmainted? The link you shared (https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) gives a 404 now

Answer (score 3):

You can still use the djangorestframework-simplejwt and modify the time in your settings file instead

settings.py

```
from datetime import timedelta

...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Check out
https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt